# Ambta Decrypt - Show plain Value

Tags: symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, doctrine

I am using [this](https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle) great encrypt/decrypt package.

It encrypts data before prePersist and decrypts is automatically postPersist.

At one part of my project I need the plain (encrypted) value from the database, is that in any way possible?

I identified this ([processFields](https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Subscribers/DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php#L217)) as the right function to change I believe, but what do I have to do?

I changed Line 277 to `$entity->$setter($getInformation);` but 1. that means NONE of the values are decrypted, and 2. it does not seem to have any effect though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you retrieve the data to be decrypted? IF you use standard DQL, when hidratate the object you have the plain data. Otherwise you need to do by yourself thru the exposed service, something like, example in a controller:

```
$pain = $this->get('ambta_doctrine_encrypt.encryptor')-> decrypt($encrypted);
```

Hope this help

Comment: With plain I meant the encrypted value from the database and I am not exactly understanding the first part but I just did this `$this->get('ambta_doctrine_encrypt.encryptor')->encrypt("MYVALUE");` and I got what I wanted! Thanks!